# Unable to create a class on the Terminal

Tags: ruby, macos, class, terminal

I am trying to create a class, following the instructions of “ruby in 20 mins” but somehow it doesn’t work.

The code it tells me to type is this:

```
irb(main):024:0> class Greeter
irb(main):025:1>   def initialize(name = "World")
irb(main):026:2>     @name = name
irb(main):027:2>   end
irb(main):028:1>   def say_hi
irb(main):029:2>     puts "Hi #{@name}!"
irb(main):030:2>   end
irb(main):031:1>   def say_bye
irb(main):032:2>     puts "Bye #{@name}, come back soon."
irb(main):033:2>   end
irb(main):034:1> end
=> nil
```

But when I do the same, the Terminal works like this:

```
irb(main):001:0> class Greeter
irb(main):002:1> def initialize(name = "World")
irb(main):003:2> @name = name
irb(main):004:2> end
irb(main):005:1> def say_hi
irb(main):006:2> puts "Hi #{@name}!}"
irb(main):007:2> end
irb(main):008:1> def say_bye
irb(main):009:2> puts "Bye #{name}, come back soon."
irb(main):010:2> end
irb(main):011:1> end
=> :say_bye
irb(main):012:0> end
```

I don’t know why there’s no indents and I suppose that is the cause of this problem.

Would you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Don't worry much about IRB's formatting. You got `=> :say_bye`, which means Ruby found nothing wrong with your code, but of course you may still get errors when you run it because syntax errors arise or  your  logic is wrong. I see no problems, however. Now try running `greeter = Greeter.new("Billy-Bob")`, then `greeter.say_hi`, then `greeter.say_bye` and see what happens.

Comment: it says:irb(main):012:0> greeter = Greeter.new("BIlly-Bob")
=> #<Greeter:0x007f862302d4a0 @name="BIlly-Bob">
irb(main):013:0> greeter.say_hi
Hi BIlly-Bob!
=> nil
irb(main):014:0> greeter.say_bye
Bye BIlly-Bob, come back soon 
=> nil
    irb(main):015:0>  So I think this is working, isn't it?

Comment: It's working as it should. btw, it's easier to read if you remove IRB's prompts when you report results. So your comment might be "It says: `greeter = ...`. Put backticks around code to make it stand out as here. On a Mac the backtick shares a key in the upper left with the tilde ~. Removing IRB's prompts allows readers to cut and paste your code.

Comment: Thanks! appreciate your help!